# mixing enum with std::map<>

Tags: c++, enums, std

I have been trying to compile the following code for a while with no success:

```
enum class gType {GAME1, GAME2, GAME3};
typedef std::map<std::string, gType> gamesTypesMap;
gamesTypesMap gameTypes;
gameTypes["game_one"] = gType::GAME1;
```

I am getting 3 errors:

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations gameTypes["game_one"] = gType::GAME1;
error: size of array has non-integer type 'const char [8]' gameTypes["game_one"] = gType::GAME1;
error: 'gType' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
```

gameTypes["game_one"] = gType::GAME1;

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this your complete code?  Where is the include for `std::map` and `std::string`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Did you remember to specify `-std=c++11` (or better)?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with c++11 enabled, very different error messages without C++11. Mingw g++ 4.8.1.

Comment: Maybe you wrote `gameTypes["game_one"] = gType::GAME1;` outside of a function?

Comment: Thanks @rici, this was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to include map and string headers and to use a compiler that supports C++11. The following code compiles on my machine with clang++

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  enum class gType {GAME1, GAME2, GAME3};
  typedef std::map<std::string, gType> gamesTypesMap;
  gamesTypesMap gameTypes;
  gameTypes["game_one"] = gType::GAME1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed missing the following in my CFLAGS: -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the includes map and string. With these include and with C++11 support enabled, your code compiled fine for me with minGW compiler.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

enum class gType {GAME1, GAME2, GAME3};
typedef std::map<std::string, gType> gamesTypesMap;

int main()
{
  gamesTypesMap gameTypes;
  gameTypes["game_one"] = gType::GAME1;
  return 0;
}
```